# Time difference in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataset containing information about flights

[image]

```
YEAR                int64
MONTH               int64
DAY                 int64
DAY_OF_WEEK         int64
AIRLINE            object
FLIGHT_NUMBER       int64
TAIL_NUMBER        object
DEPARTURE_TIME     object
ARRIVAL_TIME       object
ELAPSED_TIME      float64
CANCELLED           int64
dtype: object
```

and I want to calculate the time difference in minutes between DEPARTURE_TIME and ARRIVAL_TIME columns. The two columns have 'datetime.time' dtypes and when I try to subtract them using

```
(f.DEPARTURE_TIME-f.ARRIVAL_TIME)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I get the time difference in minutes between the two columns? I want to use this difference to subtract from EPASED_TIME column in a later step so I want to be a float.

Edit:

The original data can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/usdot/flight-delays?select=flights.csv)

The steps I followed to create the dataframe are:

```
import pandas as pd

# read dataset
flights = pd.read_csv('flights.csv',
                      dtype = {'DEPARTURE_TIME': object, 'ARRIVAL_TIME': object},
                      low_memory=False)
# keep only columns of interest
F = flights[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 
                           'DAY_OF_WEEK', 'AIRLINE',
                           'FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'TAIL_NUMBER',
                           'DEPARTURE_TIME', 'ARRIVAL_TIME', 
                           'ELAPSED_TIME', 'CANCELLED']]
# drop rows contain na 
f = F.dropna()
# format columns to datetime
f['DEPARTURE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(f['DEPARTURE_TIME'],format='%H%M', errors='coerce').dt.time

f['ARRIVAL_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(f['ARRIVAL_TIME'], format='%H%M', errors = 'coerce').dt.time
# calculate difference
(f.DEPARTURE_TIME-f.ARRIVAL_TIME)
```

Comment: Can you provide a **minimal** reproducible example directly in the question?

Comment: Those times cannot be subtracted because it's not clear whether they refer to the same day. See the duplicate for workarounds.

Comment: @timgeb. The problem is the 2 columns have not `datetime64` dtype although each cell contains a `Timestamp` instance. The solution is (probably) to convert the columns to `DatetimeIndex` with `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: I have edit the question with the steps I followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try:

```
# After pd.to_datetime
departure = pd.to_timedelta(df['DEPARTURE_TIME'].astype(str))
arrival = pd.to_timedelta(df['ARRIVAL_TIME'].astype(str))
diff = departure - arrival

diff = (diff + pd.Timedelta(days=1) 
            * (diff < pd.Timedelta(days=0))).dt.total_seconds() / 60
print(diff)

# Output
0    1186.0
1     981.0
dtype: float64
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPARTURE_TIME': ['2354', '0002'],
                   'ARRIVAL_TIME': ['0408', '0741']})
```

---

**Old answer**

Each values of your columns `DEPARTURE_TIME` and `ARRIVAL_TIME` contains `Timestamp` instance but the `dtype` is `object`.
You have to convert first your columns into `datetime64` with `pd.to_datetime()`

Try:

```
f.DEPARTURE_TIME = pd.to_datetime(f.DEPARTURE_TIME)
f.ARRIVAL_TIME = pd.to_datetime(f.ARRIVAL_TIME)

(f.DEPARTURE_TIME-f.ARRIVAL_TIME)
```